# Website within a website frame? (iframe hates me)

Tags: html

Is there any way to create a frame that loads a website other than using iFrame?

Picture this: Me, having a website and wanting to frame a blog into it, although when I use iframe the website displays correctly (for most of the part) but the links within the iframe website don't work.

I've seen many fixes although none have worked for me thus far, I'd greatly appreciate as much help as I may gain. Thank you to anyone who answers correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `frame` HTML tag, but is deprecated under `HTML5` and works almost the same as iframe. The only difference is that a frame divides the entire window and an iframe is an inline frame.

So, no, the only way is using iframes. You have to correct your blog to work with iframes (If you want).

If you don't own the iframed blog, then using iframes is not a good way to work because, for example, you don't know if they are going to add iframe breaker codes in the future, so the best way is to add a link to open in a new window/tab.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much ^_^ Html5 seems to have all the cool stuff =.= I feel as if I may just veer towards using it before I publish the page :)